# Why does my ASP.NET MVC require DTC to complete the transaction while my WPF app using the same .DLL doesn't?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msdtc

I have this transaction in a separate .DLL which is called both from a WPF app and from ASP.NET MVC. It calles two separate stored procedures in two separate databases on the same server.

Somehow the WPF app doesn't need DTC to do that while the ASP.NET MVC app does. ASP.NET MVC gives me this error: The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.

How comes the WPF app doesn't need DTC while the ASP.NET MVC app does and is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Are your connection  strings the same? How are you accessing the machine in your connection strings, machine name, IP address, domain name? Also, are you using more than one connection string in the MVC application?

Comment: my connection strings are not the same -- they're connecting to another database. Other than that they're the same yes. I'm accessing by machine name. And yes I'm using multiple connection strings in that application -- all to the same server but different databases.

Comment: Are the apps all hitting one sql server instance on the machine or do you have multiple instances installed?

Comment: @RossBush just one instance...

Comment: Post your code. Neither WPF nor ASP.NET require DTC, they aren't data access libraries. ADO.NET is the data access library. DTC is only needed if you try to use two different connections under the same transaction. You have to explicitly code this scenario.

Comment: Did you try to use the same TransactionScope with multiple connections? In that case you explicitly asked for a distributed transaction. Use a single connection instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I did try to use the same TransactionScope with multiple connections (to the same server/instance though, only a different database) but why doesn't my WPF app escalate to MSDTC while my ASP.NET MVC app which uses the exact same .DLL does?

Comment: @viking_grll I said `use the same connection` inside the transaction, not `use the same transactionscope`. As for `why`, because DTC is a *hard* requirement. If your web app works with it, it means it's available. And your queries are very, very slow because of it. It's also something that's NOT needed except in very few cases, almost *never* when connecting to the same server

Comment: Distributed transactions were in fashion back in the 00s, when people tried to integrate multiple database systems together. Needless to say, interop and performance were bad. Then came service orientation, *autonomy* and the realization that distributed transactions were a real pain. Unless you want to enlist multiple *products* in the same transaction, you don't need them at all

Comment: On the other hand, careless programming makes them reappear when they aren't needed, eg when multiple connections to the *same* server are created under a single transaction. When people use the Repository *anti*pattern on top of an ORM and try to bring back the lost transactions offered by the ORM. When data *modification* code is spread across many classes, making it hard to control changes. When pessimistic concurrency is used instead of optimistic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simply circumvented the problem now by making a stored procedure on my main database that forwards the call (ie. directly calls) the stored procedure in my secondary database. It's an acceptable design choice as the SP in my secondary database should have been in my main database to begin with, but it's there because of legacy AND this solution totally prevents MSDTC escalation so it's much more nice than having to enable that whole circuit for just this one call (in our whole system).

Comment: You only covered up the problem, you didn't even identify it. DTC is only used if you try to use two *different* connections with the same transaction. It's *not* used in cross-database transactions - if you try to use objects from multiple databases in the same query or stored procedure